# ssl error when trying to connect to a http server (apache)

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have a https client that is using ssl to connect to an apache server.

When the client try to connect to the apache server via https I got the following error:

```
SSL Library Error: 336151570 error:14094412:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert bad certificate Subject CN in certificate not server name or identical to CA!?
```

what could be the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: in ssl connection you should connect to same cn "issued to" at certificate you generate at Ca server

Answer (score 0):

> Subject CN in certificate not server name or identical to CA!?

Your certificate does not match the host nameyou access. Check your site against [SSLLabs](
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html).